# MFMailComposeViewController didFinishWithResult issue when the keyboard appears

Tags: ios, objective-c, mfmailcomposer

I've got a standard implementation of the MFMailComposeViewController.

I've set the right delegate protocols, and have a log happening on the didFinishWithResult method.

See:

```
mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
[mailComposer setSubject:emailTitle];
[mailComposer setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:YES];
mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;

[[self getController] presentViewController:mailComposer animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

---

```
- (void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"mail dismiss");
    [[self getController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

That shows the mail composer properly, and everything works well. Meaning, if I press the "cancel" button, the didFinishWithResult method gets called and the mailComposer gets dismissed.

However, if I try to type anything, such as TO: email address, or anything else in the mail composer itself, **it feels like the keyboard appearing is removing the delegate actions of my view controller, since the "cancel" and "send" buttons trigger no actions**.

Any thoughts? It's driving me crazy :/

Cheers

**EDIT**

Here's the code for getController:

```
- (UIViewController *) getController
{
    Class vcc = [UIViewController class];

    UIResponder *responder = self;
    while ((responder = [responder nextResponder]))
        if ([responder isKindOfClass: vcc])
            return (UIViewController *)responder;

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is `[self getController]` doing?

Comment: @DanielStorm - it gets the current view controller, as I'm doing this from a UIView. I've updated the code above to show that method.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but is there a chance your presentViewController is being being called from a thread other than the main thread?

Comment: and `[self presentViewController..]` doesn't work without `[[self getController] presentVC..]`?

Comment: Have you tried [self presentViewController.. while presenting and [self dismissViewController.. for dismissing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When UITextField becomeFirstResponder, than your controller recieved resignFirstResponder.

Why are you using method "getController"? Create property on ViewController which present MFMailComposeViewController.

Comment: Whilst this feels like a throwaway answer, it was the easy solution to go for. I was subclassing a view controller already, so I just added a "send email" method to it, which handles the present/dismiss of the email. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set up a switch to catch the results form the mail composer like so:

```
-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {
    switch (result) {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            // User tapped cancel button
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            // User saved email
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            // User sent email
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: Hi Daniel. I had that before and it didn't help. I don't see how that could make a difference, considering the "dismiss" is not related to the result. :/

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend this implementation:

```
- (void) presentMailViewController
    if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
        MFMailComposeViewController *mail = [MFMailComposeViewController new];
        mail.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        mail.navigationBar.tintColor = self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor;;
        [self.navigationController presentViewController:mail animated:YES completion:nil];
    }   
}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    if(error)
    {
       //...
    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

And I'd recommend you to read this page:
[Code Naming Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-1004202-BCIGGFCC)